# Watching for events returns 0 blocknumber

Tags: dapp-development, javascript, events

I am trying to listen for recently mined events from a live smartcontract([EtherDelta](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819#code)).

```
      //https://github.com/praneethmendu/ethualizer/blob/master/backnd.js

      tradeEvent = contractIns.Trade({}, {fromBlock: '4221476', toBlock: 'latest'});

      tradeEvent.watch(function (error, eventResult) {
          if (error) {
              console.error(error);
          } else {
              loco.play();
              console.log(JSON.stringify(eventResult, null, 4));
          }
```

I am returned results by the watch callback but blocknumber and other hashes and indexes are 0, although args seem genuine, I suspect I am looking at pending transactions

```
{
    "address": "0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819",
    "blockNumber": 0,
    "transactionHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "transactionIndex": 0,
    "blockHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "logIndex": 0,
    "removed": false,
    "event": "Trade",
    "args": {
        "tokenGet": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "amountGet": "3909184320983949755",
        "tokenGive": "0xe41d2489571d322189246dafa5ebde1f4699f498",
        "amountGive": "4.093386723543402884816e+21",
        "get": "0x798888341bfc01b30196091d27613fc6c68df159",
        "give": "0xafe15d1c5baab8f6fc9ba107a90a5729964ea14c"
    }
}
```

I can get the current latest block and interact with getters in the contract, I am using a geth lightnode in rpc mode to connect, so no connectivity problems.

other details :
OS: Ubuntu 17.04

Edit: improved question using @farhankhwaja 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have missed something in here. I was able to capture the EVENT of my contract which I deployed on the TestNet.

> Requirements

```
1. ABI - The contract ABI
2. Contract Address 
3. Web3js
```

> Code

```
var myContractInstance = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(*<ABI>*)).at(*<CONTRAC_ADDRESS>*);

// Watching for MyEvent
var myEvent = myContractInstance.MyEvent({}, {fromBlock: '0', toBlock: 'latest'});

myEvent.get(function (error, eventResult) {
    if (error) {
         console.error(error);
    }
    else {
        loco.play();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(eventResult, null, 4));
    }
});
```

The above code if executed, will return you all the transactions in which the Event was called.

> Example Transaction

```
{
        "address": "0x5c99dadde01ce61ab5b5536d566bf41ecd17e3a9",
        "blockNumber": 1495157,
        "transactionHash": "0x41fe9e995dba27c422ac5d0e9f1c8360ac512c3767c2217a0e729ed0b6098aa6",
        "transactionIndex": 0,
        "blockHash": "0x833c293455edb27c266fc2a0fbdab97431137c2f3d690c19835ddcf59ed4fe8a",
        "logIndex": 0,
        "removed": false,
        "event": "MyEevent",
        "args": {
            "_from": "0xb1aa0ac057639e534a89b095853befc4d6d264cf",
            "_to": "0x5c99dadde01ce61ab5b5536d566bf41ecd17e3a9",
            "_value": "1",
            "_tokenAddress": "0x85c02a9957f87445298eadffce717b7d256d6542",
            "_tokenName": "CC Series",
            "_tokenSymbol": "CC"
        }
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't give you the desired result.

Comment: my code is at https://github.com/praneethmendu/ethualizer/blob/master/backnd.js . I can get latest block and interact with getters, so requirements are taken care of. Despite using your code I still get results as shown in the question with block number, hashes and index as 0.  

I am watching for 'trade' event calls by EtherDelta. So I am working with main net.

I suspect I am listening for 'pending' events instead of 'latest' transactions

Comment: @praneethmendu I ran your code and I was able to get the logs for the event. Some questions:

1. Is your Client 'geth/parity' sync with the MainNet? What is the output when your run `web3.eth.blockNumber` after connecting to your Client.

The value/Output of the above command should be the block number being shown on [EtherScan](https://etherscan.io/)

Comment: I'm using : geth --syncmode "light" --cache=1024 -rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" and I manage to get the latest block alright

Comment: This may be because of running geth in light mode ??

Comment: I think you will need to use "fast".**Full Sync:** Gets the block headers, the block bodies, and validate every element from genesis block.
**Fast Sync:** Gets the block headers, the block bodies, it performs no validation until current block - 1024. Then it gets a snap shot state and goes like a full synchronization.
**Light Sync**: Gets only the current state. To verify elements, it needs to ask to full (archive) nodes for the corresponding tree leaves. **Note**: with the above description you will need to use fast/full